# How can I run a process from Perl and capture both output and return code?

Tags: multithreading, perl, process, fork

I would like to run a separate process in Perl (a command line PHP script).  I would like to capture this processes output AND return code.  Optionally I would like to be able to terminate the process and move on if the process takes longer than N seconds.  What should I look into?

Comment: Now it says "Perl" and your comments can be deleted.

Comment: Please don't revert the edit back to uppercase. :) It really is ["perl" or "Perl", but not "PERL"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq1.html#What's-the-difference-between-%22perl%22-and-%22Perl%22%3f)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/IPC-Run-0.92/lib/IPC/Run.pm).

> IPC::Run - system() and background procs w/ piping, redirs, ptys (Unix, Win32)

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I find the easiest is [AnyEvent](https://metacpan.org/module/AnyEvent) with [AnyEvent::Util](https://metacpan.org/module/AnyEvent%3a%3aUtil)::run_cmd and a timer.  There is no requirement here to run your entire program under an event loop, I regularly go in and out of the event loops with this solution today.  (The following isn't warnings-safe.)

```
use AnyEvent;
use AnyEvent::Util;

my ($stdout, $stderr, $pid);

my $cv = AnyEvent::Util::run_cmd [ $^X, -e => '$|++; sleep 2; print "foo\n"; sleep 2' ],
    '>'  => \$stdout,
    '2>' => \$stderr,
    '$$' => \$pid,
;

my $w = AnyEvent->timer(after => 3, interval => 0, cb => sub { print "killing!\n"; kill SIGINT => $pid });

my $rc = $cv->recv();
$w = undef; # end the timer.

print "got rc = [$rc]\n";
print "stdout = [$stdout]\n";
print "stderr = [$stderr]\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use piped **open()** to get all 3 goals:

```
my $pid = open(F, "cat /etc/passwd |") || die "Cant open pipe: $!";
eval {
     # Give 30 secs to read output:
     local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { kill(9, $pid); die "alarm\n"; }; # NB: \n required
     alarm(30);

     # Read output:
     my $line = <F>;
     alarm(0); # Remove alarm

     #..do job with $line
};
# Get errorcode:
close(F);
print "Exit status: $?\n";
printf "Exit value(return code): %d\n", $?>>8;
print "Killed by timeout\n" if ($? & 127)==9;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use IPC::System::Simple qw/EXIT_ANY $EXITVAL capture/;

my $output = capture(EXIT_ANY, 'some command');
print "exit value was $EXITVAL\n";
```

`EXIT_ANY` tells capture to allow any exit value; you can instead list allowed ones (`capture([0,1,42], ...)`) and capture will throw an exception if another is encountered.  By default (if just a command is passed to capture) any non-zero exit value results in an exception.

Answer (score 1):

This is a frequently asked question. Have a look at this [Perl FAQ](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-can-I-capture-STDERR-from-an-external-command?) too. It basically explains the way to run external commands in Perl.

Answer (score 0):

Without considering the optional part of your question, you can obtain the output of a command within backticks, and its return value in the special variable `$?`.

```perl
my $output = `shell_command`;
die ("shell_command failed!\n") if ($?);
```