# Need to run git command from perl and have to capture the result of the command at the end

Tags: git, perl

I need to run git commands from perl script. For this i need to use complete path of the git. the syntax looks like this

```
system "start", "cmd.exe", "/k", "cd $Repo_path && $arg1 && exit";
```

Where `$arg1 = git/exe/path` git command.

Some time the execution of command may get failed due to some reasons. I need to capture the status of the result of the command executed. Atleast if I am able to capture Success or failure, that would also be great. Any help to this is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run a process from Perl and capture both output and return code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572710/how-can-i-run-a-process-from-perl-and-capture-both-output-and-return-code)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bperl%5D+capture+code+and+output

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the generic ways of executing external commands, [Git::Wrapper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Git::Wrapper) may be useful for this specific case. It abstracts running git commands into a standard Perl object interface. You can pass a specific git binary and git directory for it to use as the `git_binary` and `dir` constructor parameters, as mentioned in the synopsis, and it throws exceptions if there is an error, which you can catch and handle with [various methods](http://mvp.kablamo.org/cpan/exceptions/).